# How to apply function zip to n-list

Tags: python, arrays, list

The example applied the function zip to two alist is this:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
zipped = zip(x, y)
#show
list(zipped)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

But now if I've some like :

```py
array = [   [1,2,3], [3,4,5] , [6,7,8] ... ]
```

How to applied the function zip to show some like:

```py
[(1,3,6,...),(2,4,7,...),(3,5,8,...),... (....) ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) via the "splat" or "star" operator:

```
zip(*array)
```

example:

```
>>> array = [   [1,2,3], [3,4,5] , [6,7,8]  ]
>>> print ( list(zip(*array)) )
[(1, 3, 6), (2, 4, 7), (3, 5, 8)]
```